# How can one link to a specific portion of an article?

Tags: links, wikipedia

I wish to link to a specific portion of a Wikipedia article. For example in [this article about Mahatma Gandhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi), I wish to create a direct link to the section `Struggle for Indian Independence` without showing the other details above. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a link directly to that section of the page.  It won't hide any page content but it will skip directly to the linked section.

Copy section links from the **Contents** box located at the top left of the page.

For example, on Wikipedia's [Mahatma Gandhi page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi), if you copy the link to [Struggle for Indian independence (1915–1947)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi#Struggle_for_Indian_independence_(1915%E2%80%931947)) from the **Contents** you'll get the URL
`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi#Struggle_for_Indian_Independence_.281915.E2.80.9347.29`
which links directly to that section of the page.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ###### [How do you get the URL of specific section on a Wikipedia page](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-get-the-URL-of-specific-section-on-a-Wikipedia-page/answer/Betsy-Megas)
>
> <sup>~ Betsy Megas, Quora</sup>
>
> On most longer pages in Wikipedia and other Mediawiki wikis, look for a Table of Contents box and click on any of the headings there. For example, on the page for Benjamin Franklin, there’s a section called *Newspaperman*.
>
> The table of contents should appear automatically on pages with multiple named sections, but you should also be able to create the URL manually by appending # and the exact name of the section (case sensitive, with underscores for spaces) at the end of the URL, as in: `/Benjamin_Franklin#Newspaperman`.

This worked for me at [https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/Issue_Reporting#:~:text=More%20markup%20help-,contents,-hide](https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/Issue_Reporting#:%7E:text=More%20markup%20help-,contents,-hide) (another wiki using the same MediaWiki software that Wikipedia does). For example, https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/Issue_Reporting#Step_4:_Log_into_or_set_up_a_Bugzilla_account

Comment: Per your comments, I edited [the accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92153) to make it clearer. You can also improve other users' posts and are encouraged to do so,  and you receive reputation points when you do.

Answer (score 0):

A wikipedia page is along the time contributed to. It is often good to keep and to share a link to some specific revision.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mahatma_Gandhi&diff=prev&oldid=644197118#Struggle_for_Indian_Independence_.281915.E2.80.9347.29

A link like this is not going away if people in the future make a change in the section title or re-order section structures.

(Above is the very edition introducing sentence: "At the request of Gokhale, conveyed to him by C.F. Andrews, Gandhi returned to India in 1915".)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link to a specific section of a Wikipedia page by combining the page URL with the section's title.

1. **Find the page's URL**
   For example, the URL for the Wikipedia page **[Cattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle)** is:
   `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle`
2. **Find title of the section**

   - Use the title of the specific section without any parent section titles. For example, for the **Sleep** section under **Behavior**, `Cattle page > Behavior > Sleep`, it would be **Sleep**
   - Any spaces in the title must be replaced by underscores `_` and the existing capitalization must be matched exactly.  For example, the title for **Grazing behavior**, `Cattle page > Behavior > Grazing behavior` would be **Grazing_behavior**
3. **Combine the `URL` with a hash `#` and the `Title`**
   Examples:

   - `Cattle page > Behavior` 
     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle#Behavior
   - `Cattle page > Behavior > Grazing behavior`
      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle#Grazing_behavior

Answer (score 0):

> without showing the other details above

nope, but you can get pretty close using [Scroll to Text Fragment](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096). Using the article and section you mentioned as an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi#:%7E:text=monuments.%5B92%5D-,Struggle%20for%20Indian%20independence%20(1915%E2%80%931947),though%20the%20veracity%20of%20this%20statement%20has%20been%20questioned.%5B212%5D,-Principles%2C%20practices%2C%20and).